# Can I use a wireless modem instead of wireless adaptor

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I have 2 wireless modems at the moment. One is connected to my ADSL provider and all the wi-fi devices are connect to it currently. Second one is sitting idle at the moment.

I also have a PC that doesnt have an wireless connection option due to lack of wireless network card/adaptor.

What I aim to do is, connect that PC to my second modem using ethernet cable, and connect that modem to first modem through wireless connection, effectively making second modem act like a wireless adaptor for my PC.

Is this configuration possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, but the process of setting it up varies a great deal depending on which model of router you have. Search Google for the model of router followed by relevant keywords like `wireless bridge` or `client mode` or refer to the router's user guide.

Comment: It appears you're confusing the terms [modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem#Broadband) and [wireless router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_router).  Please review these links and edit your question accordingly.  Additionally, as written your question is too broad.  Consider asking a more narrow question such as *"How do I wirelessly connect wireless router Model X to my ADSL modem/router model Y?"*

Answer (score 1):

Yes you absolutely can. Search for 
dd-wrt and see if your router is supported. If it is, you can install custom firmware which allows you to use your router as an adapter or a gamut of other things.